# Pandas read .csv separated by whitespace but columns with names that contain spaces

Tags: pandas, csv, whitespace, separator

I have a .csv file that have to read. It is separated by a whitespace but the column names also have spaces. Something like this:

```
column1 another column final column  
value ONE valueTWO valueTHREE
```

I have been trying to read it withthis but it confuses with the spaces of the column names (not separators). I tried using read_fwf and read_csv but did not worked:

```
df_mccf=pd.read_fwf(r'C:\Users\MatíasGuerreroIrarrá\OneDrive - BIWISER\Orizon\MCCF\inputs\valores-MCCF (3).csv',\
                   colspecs=[(0, 4), (5, 10), (11, 21), (22, 32), (33, 54), (55, 1000)])
```

and:

```
df_mccf=pd.read_fwf(r'C:\Users\MatíasGuerreroIrarrá\OneDrive - BIWISER\Orizon\MCCF\inputs\valores-MCCF (3).csv',\
                   sep=' ')
```

[get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey7h0.png)

and with this line:

```
df_mccf=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\MatíasGuerreroIrarrá\OneDrive - BIWISER\Orizon\MCCF\inputs\valores-MCCF (3).csv',\
                   encoding='UTF-16', delim_whitespace=True)
```

[got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psS6L.png)

Any help would be really amazing.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have that many columns. What if you manually edit the column names, and replace the spaces with underscores?

Comment: I could do that, the problem is that the code goes to productive and the file with always be with the spaces when automated. The ideal would be to read it like it comes.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you ignore the header altogether and instead pass the [`names`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) argument. That way you can use the whitespace separator for the rest of the file:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """column one column two column three
a 1 x
b 2 y
"""

with io.StringIO(data) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        f,
        delim_whitespace=True,
        names=['one', 'two', 'three'],  # custom header names
        skiprows=1,  # Skip the initial row (header)
    )
```

Result:

```
  one  two three
0   a    1     x
1   b    2     y
```

Comment: Thanks, just edited the question because some values of the Dataframe also contain names with spaces on it, do you have some idea how to handle also that?

Comment: @MatiasGuerreroIrarrázaval Are the values by any chance quoted? If there isn't a way to tell "value" spaces from delimiter spaces, there's not much you can do. If you have any access to the process generating these awful "CSV" files, you should try to fix it there.